# Discord.py Ban and Hackban command error // AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ban'

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm not sure what the issue is as this works perfectly for all my other bots! Does anyone know how to fix this.

```
@client.command(description="Bans People!") # Bans people
@commands.has_any_role('Staff')
async def ban(ctx, x: typing.Union[discord.Member, int], *, reason=None):
    guild = client.get_guild(1037550844935147622)
    if x in ctx.guild.members:
        await x.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'Banned {x.mention}')
    else:
        await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=x))
        await ctx.reply(f'User has been hackbanned!\nUser: <@{x}>')
```

```
Ignoring exception in command ban:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\13129\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 184, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\13129\Desktop\Python Bot\will.py", line 398, in ban
    await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=x))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ban'
```

What I was expecting was to have the person banned outside of the server. It just doesn't work but works with my other bots.

Comment: [`get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild) returns `None` if no guild is found. Are you sure your bot has access to this guild?

Comment: @Benjin I'm not sure because I've tried ```guild = ctx.guild``` with no avail... The exact code works for 3 of my other bots and this one decides to have the issue with wrapped and it not having the attribute 'ban'

Answer (score 0):

You Need Convert The `ID Object` To `User Object` \

`from discord.utils import get` 
`user = get(bot.get_all_members(), id="your id")`

**User Object Has Ban Method Not The ID**

Comment: Same error! I honestly think it's something to do with the bot or something else I have in the code. It works on all my other bots which really confuses me

Comment: Maybe Server Perms !

Comment: The bot has perms ;-;

Comment: What About Intents?